# On button click in Extjs 4.0.2

Tags: extjs

on button two Ajax request send to ".cfm" page, for two times button click it's working fine but in third time when i button press the Error "an ajax response error has occured.

```
function ViewOpenPoll() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:QVisibleLink,
        // ON button click function viewpoll invoke
        // and the given url in ajax request has send.
        disableCaching: true,
        success: function(response) {
            obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: function ViewOpenPoll() {  Ext.Ajax.request({
          url:QVisibleLink,
ON button click function viewpoll invoke and the given url in ajax request has send.          disableCaching : true,
          success : function(response) {
           obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);});}

Comment: @pratibind jha: You can edit your original question and add the code there in nicely formatted way. Did it for you this time.

Comment: Is the ajax call reaching the server? Is there any error on server side? is there any error code reported by firebug?

Answer (score 1):

Access the .cfm page directly with your browser 3 times in a row. Does it work?